# How to specify in a code that it must be a number, because if I enter a word in an integer input the program crashes

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tell me the code that would support this, because if I enter a word into an integer input the program crashes. I know this would be a simple one line code, but I just can't get my head around it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "N:/Controlled Assessment/Task Three v1.py", line 9, in <module>
    c1_strength = int(input("What is character 1's strength? (Between 1 and 50, must be number): ")) #asks user for the strength value of character 1
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'fresd'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
while True:
    try:
        a = int(input())
    except ValueError:
        print "Enter an integer"
        continue
    break
```

Comment: 1. use `input()` instead of `raw_input()` because OP uses Python 3 otherwise he would get `NameError` on the `input()` call. 2. `a.isdigit()`, `int(a)` and `re.match('\s*\d+\s*$', a)` may have different ideas about what a number is. It is best to use `try: result = int(a) except ValueError` directly

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I agree with you on the `input()` part, but i don't agree  in the second part. The OP specified that the input should be integers. So this should work right?

Comment: @AswinMurugesh See `EAFP` [here](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html)

Comment: no e.g., `'\u2466'.isdigit()` is true but `int('\u2466')` produces `ValueError`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: Got it!!

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: How about now?

Comment: don't use bare `except:` use `except ValueError` instead.